# How to correctly bind to an Itemsource inside an datatemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, itemsource

I am using an `ItemsControl` which has a list of Objects... inside the `ItemContainerTemplate` I have another `DataTemplate`. Inside of that `DataTemplate` I can't bind to the `ItemsControl.ItemSource` anymore.

Since I am not very good with bindings via `Find Ancestor` and `RelativeSource` etc. I tried everything without even knowing how to properly use them...

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding NoteList}">
  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <ItemContainerTemplate>
      <GroupBox Header="{Binding Title}"
                Name="MyNoteList"
                Style="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignCardGroupBox}"
                Margin="16">
        <GroupBox.HeaderTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
            <DockPanel>
              <TextBlock Margin="8,0,0,0"
                         VerticalAlignment="Center"
                         Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignSubheadingTextBlock}"
                         Text="{Binding}" />
              <Button Padding="5"
                      Command="{Binding DataContext.DeleteCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"
                      CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}, Path=DataContext.NoteId}"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                      Background="Transparent"
                      BorderBrush="Transparent">
                <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="Delete"
                                         Height="25"
                                         Width="25"
                                         VerticalAlignment="Center" />
              </Button>
            </DockPanel>
          </DataTemplate>
        </GroupBox.HeaderTemplate>
      </GroupBox>
    </ItemContainerTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

I like to mention, that I want to bind to an object from `NoteList` with the name `NoteId` inside the `CommandParameter`. But I keep getting "null" from it. The binding inside my ViewModel is definitely correct. So i only need to know, how to access the `NoteId` Property from my `NoteList`

Answer (score 1):

I actually got the Problem solved myself! xD ! I did only have to bind to an Element inside my `ItemContainerTemplate`, in my case to the `GroupBox` (seen in the code snippet above).

```
CommandParameter="{Binding DataContext.NoteId, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type GroupBox}}}"
```

Comment: Thats true if you are accessing an `Item` inside an `DataTemplate`, in my case, iam inside an `DataTemplate` which is in another `ItemContainerTemplate`, i want to acces the Parent of the `DataTemplate` iam already inside :)